facebook_audience_network - swiftCompatibility56
I am add package to my flutter project : facebook_audience_network
But when build always say :
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56
i try all version but always say same problem
even i create new project with out anything just i add facebook_audience_network package but when build say :
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

